# adding src/main/aspect as a source folder to an eclipse maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, import, aspectj

I would like to be able to configure the pom.xml so that when I import it into eclipse it specifies `src/main/aspect` as an eclipse source folder.

At the moment, importing creates the default source folders but that is all.

What should be done?

Thanks

**edit 1**

I have configured the aspectj plugin thus:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions> 
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>    
            <goal>test-compile</goal>                           
        </goals>
         <configuration>
            <source>${project.build.source}</source>
            <target>${project.build.target}</target>
            <aspectDirectory>src/main/aspect</aspectDirectory>
            <testAspectDirectory>src/test/aspect</testAspectDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

**edit 2**

I have configured the m2e plugin thus:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>
                            org.codehaus.mojo
                        </groupId>
                        <artifactId>
                            aspectj-maven-plugin
                        </artifactId>
                        <versionRange>
                            [1.4,)
                        </versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <ignore></ignore>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you using an other plugin for AspectJ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Please see my edit (1)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't configure the [defaults of the plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html), cause it defines already the src/test/aspect and src/main/aspect and it shouldn't be necessary to configuration something supplemental to compile etc.

Furthermore the problem with eclipse could be based on a missing [mapping for your m2e plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) this means to add the following to your build:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.4,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute />
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This might cause you problem in Eclipse not to see the source folder correctly imported.

Comment: I already have this mapping, only difference is the action which I had set to <ignore/> - the default, I think. I have now changed it to be <execute/>, like yours, deleted the project from eclipse, re-imported it, and still no src/main/aspect source directory...

Comment: Have you deleted the .project, .classpath and the .settings folder as well? Only deleting the project from eclipse will not delete the folders and files from the file system.

Comment: Thanks, I now retried while deleting the files/folders you had specified, yet the result is the same... the `src/main/aspect` folder does not get added as a source folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`source`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html) is supposed to be a java version, not a directory.  Same for `target`.  `sources` allows you to specify the source directories, and the docs say that if not specified, the java sources of the current project will be used - just one for your project as configured currently.

I would try listing the directories in the `sources` parameter, and if that didn't work, I'd remove `sources` and try [build-helper:add-source](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-source-mojo.html).  I'm not sure there's an m2e connector for `build-helper-maven-plugin` yet so you might have to add a similar mapping to the one khmarbaise mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, concerning `source` and `target` I had set them to the version same as you said: `<properties>
 <project.build.source>1.6</project.build.source>
 <project.build.target>1.6</project.build.target>
</properties>` ... I will take a look at the build-helper though

Answer (score 0):

I think it would not be added as source folder by Eclipse. you could add it on your own in `Java Build Path > Source`.

This is not necessary: Then you need to have [AJDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/%E2%80%8E) installed in and convert the project to AspectJ Project, otherwise the `.aj`files will be full of errors complained by Eclipse. The errors does not affect maven compiling.

In my experience, recognized or not as source would not affect maven compiling the `.aj` files under `src/main/aspect`

Both [aspectDirectory](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#aspectDirectory) and [`aspectTestDirectory`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#testAspectDirectory) have default values as you given. they are not needed if the same as default.

Here below is my pom configuration (didn't try `test-compile`) and it works:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <!--<Xlint>ignore</Xlint>--><!--bypass xlint warnings -->
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```